# Underline appears between reputation graph month names on hover

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

On [my profile page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/60685/djdavid98?tab=topactivity), when I hover over the reputation graph, an underline appears between the month names. I'm using Chrome 44.0.2403.157 on Windows 10.

> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixed now, it will be live after our next production build.